# Screenshare from Ubuntu 18.04 to Roku 3 on the same Wi-Fi

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, miracast

**I've tried everything, including:**

MiracleCast (couldn't figure out how to use it)

NetworkManager Wifi Direct (couldn't figure out how to build it, i'm new to linux and building programs)

A browser extension (Nothing Happened)

I'm looking for a one-click download and installer I can just run and apparently nobody has that. If that isn't possible, next best thing is a clear tutorial on what exactly I need to do to stream video URLS from PC to Roku.